# How do I fix Expected end of Statement?

Tags: javascript, hta

How would I fix,"Expected End Of Statement" in the code below?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function substitute() {
  var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

  if (myValue.length === 0) {
    alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
    return;
  }
  var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
  myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;

}
</script>
```

It keeps telling me line 57 which is this line:

```
  <input type="submit" value="Click Me" onClick="substitute();">
```

Here is the complete HTA link:
http://pastebin.com/fMg5e4RN

Comment: Fixed those typos, sorry been a long day where I live, but I still get that error :/

Comment: Well that validation code is not going to work and the type attribute is wrong.

Comment: Could you show me the correct code?

Comment: True. Use `<form onsubmit="return substitute()"` and return true or false depending on validation. Remove type="javascript" or fix it as text/javascript

Comment: @mplungjan Must I add this to line 57?

Comment: Also what is the variable "title" ?

Comment: Title is <p id="title"></p>

Comment: Fixed the text/javascript

Comment: In your code you have `title.innerHTML`, `title` is not defined anywhere. You also never cancel the click event for the page will submit. What is actually generating the message "Expected end of Statement"?

Comment: Title is defined later on in the rest of my code.

Comment: Incorrect, you defined it as `myTitle`. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<form onsubmit="return substitute()"` and return true or false depending on validation. Remove type="javascript" or fix it as text/javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function substitute() {
  var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

  if (myValue.length === 0) {
    alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
    return false;
  }
  // not sure what the following two lines are for
  var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
  myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
  return true; // allow submit

}
</script>
```

and use

```
<form action="some action"  onsubmit="return substitute();">
  <input type="text" id="myTextBox"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it jumps to line 63 witch is:
     <input type="text" id="myTextBox">
      <form action="some action"  onsubmit="return substitute();">

Comment: Then you have some other error. Post the complete html. Also the form tag belongs BEFORE the input field and you need. </form> after the last field

Comment: You are welcome You do have several issues in your HTA. You need to call function names in the events - I would rewrite the whole thing in EITHER javascript OR vbscript.